# Validation to require a field updated

Tags: validation-rule

I need a couple number fields updated when a checkbox is checked, but if there's already info in the number fields I want it updated.  Here's what I have:

```
AND(
Field_Follow_CAxT__c = True,
OR(
ISBLANK(FF_Service_Engineer_CAxT__c),
ISBLANK(TEXT(Expected_Date_of_Completion_FF_CAxT__c)),
ISBLANK(TEXT(NPI_Program_Number_CAxT__c)),
AND(
ISBLANK(Command_AxT_Onboard_Version__c),
ISCHANGED(Command_AxT_Onboard_Version__c)),

ISBLANK((Command_AxT_Onboard_Build__c))
)
)
```

It saves even if I don't update the fields with info in them already.  If I change the second `AND` to `OR` it errors no matter what I do with the number fields.

Comment: Could you explain in a bit more detail what you want your validation to do?

Comment: when the Field_Follow_CAxT__c checkbox is checked, there are 5 fields that need to be filled in.  Sometimes Command_AxT_Onboard_Version__c already has info, but if its in Field Follow the Command_AxT_Onboard_Version__c needs to be updated.  So if its blank, needs to be updated and if its already filled in, it needs to be updated.

Comment: Do not validate multiple fields in a single formula. This provides a bad user experience. It'd be a lot easier to make this 4 or 5 validation rules, as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:
If I'm understanding your use case corectly, your validation rule needs to check when the checkbox is changed to true if any of the other fields are blank OR NOT changed.

Assuming that when the checkbox is checked, all other fields need to be changed AND have a value (not be blank), you would need something like this (this is NOT the full formula, of course):

```
AND(
Field_Follow_CAxT__c = True,
ISCHANGED( Field_Follow_CAxT__c ),

OR(
ISBLANK( FF_Service_Engineer_CAxT__c),
NOT( ISCHANGED( FF_Service_Engineer_CAxT__c)),
ISBLANK( TEXT( Expected_Date_of_Completion_FF_CAxT__c)),
NOT( ISCHANGED( TEXT( Expected_Date_of_Completion_FF_CAxT__c))),

(then repeat with every field that must be updated when box is checked)
```

Comment: Also semi related, but worth noting that it is not entirely necessary to use the " = true" part for the checkbox field, since by default its output is already boolean. However, you would of course need to specify if you were testing against the opposite value (something evaluating to true when checkbox is false). Though you may have done it for visual clarity, which I do sometimes as well.

Comment: `NOT(Checkbox_Field__c)` takes care of the checkbox = false scenario.